# Reading JSON from Rails server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json

I've been following the example from [here](http://d-codepages.com/android-simple-json-parsing-example/) to read JSON data from a server.

From my app, I can read from the server that the example provided in their website.

However, when I have created a JSON path to test whether I can get information from my [server](http://ohnu93_xretn5drg_dkhspe.run.goorm.io:46665/show.json), it gives me NullPointerException error at line 81 (marked with comment, //here) of the code below.

```
protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL).build();

        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            return response.body().string(); //here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

At first, I thought I had done something wrong with setting up the server on my side. But after some search through the web and seeing no "special" things to be done to rather than having JSON objects for the JSON file, I am guessing that the error is not because of this.

Can anyone help me please?

p.s. in case the server link doesn't work because the server is off, here's the code of my JSON file.

`/views/user/show.json.erb`

```
{
    <% @user.each do |record| %>
    {
        "id" => <%= record.id %>
        "name" => <%= record.name %>
        "age" => <%= record.age %>
    }

    <% end %>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a template to generate a JSON file on your server is quite strange.

The JSON syntax is wrong on several points:

- You probably want to return a *list* of users instead of a dictionary.
- Elements in a list should be separated by a comma.
- There is no `=>`in a dictionary. The syntax should be `"key": "value"`.

Usually, with ruby on rails, you don't need to use `.erb`files to return a JSON. You could simply the the render function, that will automatically transform the given object into a JSON and return it to the client:

```
render json: @user.map {|record| { id: record.id, name: record.name, age: record.age } }
```

Comment: Thank you! it turned out that my c9 server was blocking post requests... :S

Answer (score 0):

You're not constructing valid json. Try to for example the [jbuilder gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), which is at the moment the suggested method, to create your json files. Your code would turn into this:

```
# app/views/user/show.json.jbuilder

json.array! @user, :id, :name, :age
```

Similar to the examples in the README of the gem.

Comment: Thank you! it turned out that my c9 server was blocking post requests... :S